# ZentriOS hup POST request to upload text file using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We are requesting to AWS API Gateway URL, using ZentriOS hup command to upload text files. Here we are getting following error:

Error with TLS handshake: 5018 (state: 2, code: 0X28)

Screenshot attached to reference:

[image]